# How to make one field dependable of another field in models? Django

Tags: python, django

How to make one field dependable on another? for example

```
class Example(models.Model):
    question = models.BooleanField()
```

then if question is True:

```
    example1 = models.ForeignKey('Object1')
```

when false:

```
    example2 = models.ForeignKey('Object2')
```

or something like that? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use a [Generic Foreign Key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1) which allows for polymorphic types. This avoids the extra column.